# How can I run a c++ application on gnome-terminal directly from Eclipse instead of its console?

Tags: gnome-terminal, c++, eclipse

Trying here to set a c++ application to run on `gnome-terminal` instead of eclipse console from within eclipse itself.

Already done it with Java, but with c++ the menus are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's it, finally managed to enable it, took 6 hours researching. Got it with help from `https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/305157/`.

Entered in Run Configuration, in  perspective and set:

At Main tab:

Project: nameofproject

C/C++ Application: `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`

Arguments tab:

Program arguments: `-e ./nameofproject`*

** you can add `--window-with-profile=PROFILENAME` gnome-terminal setting to run it with other profiles.

Working directory:

Here set the exactly file location directory:

`${workspace_loc:nameofproject/Debug}`

And deselect 'Use default'

Environment tab:

No changes

Common tab:

Deselect Allocate Console (necessary for input) in Standard Input and Output frame.

Apply and run.